# Using wget, download a website translated by google translate

Tags: wget

I want to download(recursively) http://e-maxx.ru/algo , after it has been translated to english using Google translate.

Comment: It's harder than I thought. I've tried translating a single url with `curl -G --data-urlencode "u=http://e-maxx.ru/algo" 'http://translate.google.com/translate' --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0"`. But translation is in another frame. I've fetched that (` grep -o 'src="/translate_p[^"]*"' | cut -d'"' -f2 `), again got the master page without translation. Google's making it hard to scape translate.

Comment: note also that Google Translate has no API anymore, so scraping is the only way to do it